How to return final response of query in Nestjs
I have API to get list of all the liked (favorite) requests and projects as below.
So whenever we like request and later that request might get converted to project, so it should remain liked irrespective of phase(request/project).
API query is as below to get the list of likes
 async getAllLikeByUser(type: RequestType, user: User) {
    let qb;
      qb = this.createQueryBuilder('l')
        .select([
          'l.id as id',
          'l.user_id',
          'l.type as type',
          'l.request_id',,
          'cp.phase as phase',
        ])
        .addSelect(
          `CASE
            WHEN l.type='${RequestType.CF_R}' THEN cp.project_name
            WHEN l.type='${RequestType.BWR}' THEN bwr.project_title 
            WHEN l.type='${RequestType.MR_R}' THEN mrr.mrr_name
            WHEN l.type='${RequestType.CF_P}' THEN cp.project_name
          END`,
          'name'
        )
        .leftJoin('content_production', 'cp', 'cp.request_id = l.request_id')
        .leftJoin('brand_website_request', 'bwr', 'bwr.touch_point_request_id = l.request_id')
        .leftJoin('market_research_request', 'mrr', 'mrr.id = l.request_id')
        .where('l.user_id = :userId', { userId: user.id });
      if (type) {
        qb.andWhere('l.type = :type', { type: type });
      }
      qb.orderBy(`l.id`, 'DESC');

  // I have added below code to check the result from above query if any of the request is converted to project if yes then we will update the Like table with type as CF_P and then the final result should be with the updated data.

      const result = await qb.getRawMany();
      for (const rawResult of result) {
        if (rawResult.phase == 2 && rawResult.type === 'CF_R') {
          const request_id = rawResult.request_id;
          qb = this.createQueryBuilder().update(Like).set({ type: RequestType.CF_P });
          qb.where('request_id = :request_id', {
            request_id,
          }).execute();
        }
      }
 // piece of code added by me ends here

    return qb.getRawMany();
  }


Currently the above is giving internal server error
and the update like table is working , but final response is not coming(internal server error because of the code piece added to check phase and type
I have to check the type and phase from the select query if the condition satisfies
if (rawResult.phase == 2 && rawResult.type === 'CF_R') then update the type in LIKE table and return the response with updated data.
In the below response initially request_id :492 was of type CF_R => Request and later converted as Project so it should get updated type as CF_P as below
Final response should be as below:
Phase :1 => Request
Phase :2 => Project
[
  {
    "phase":2
    "id": 491,
    "user_id": 126,
    "type": "CF_P",
    "request_id": 492,
    "name": "test"
  },
  {
    "phase":2,
    "id": 487,
    "user_id": 126,
    "type": "CF_P",
    "request_id": 493,
    "name": "test2"
  },
  {     
    "id": 148,
    "user_id": 126,
    "type": "BWR",
    "request_id": 354,
    "name": "Testqwerty"
  },
  {
    "id": 45,
    "user_id": 126,
    "type": "MR_R",
    "request_id": 325,
    "name": "2023-04_Albania"
  }
]

